# split command suffix generation/increments

Tags: linux

Can someone explain to me how the `split` command suffix generation works?

From https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html#split-invocation I get that

> By default split will initially create files with two generated suffix characters, and will increase this width by two when the next most significant position reaches the last character. (‘yz’, ‘zaaa’, ‘zaab’, …).

Why does it skip from `yz` to `zaaa` without using `za` to `zz` ?

Example:
A 50MB file `dd if=/dev/urandom of=foo bs=1M count=50` split with `split -b 1b foo`

Checking with `ls -lah | less`

I find the first increment is at around line 600 (`:600g` inside `less`):

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  512 ene 20 17:33 xyw
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  512 ene 20 17:33 xyx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  512 ene 20 17:33 xyy
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  512 ene 20 17:33 xyz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  512 ene 20 17:33 xzaaa
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  512 ene 20 17:33 xzaab
```

In between I find:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  512 ene 20 17:33 xzazy
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  512 ene 20 17:33 xzazz <--- Here it reaches zz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  512 ene 20 17:33 xzbaa
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  512 ene 20 17:33 xzbab
```

I find the second increment at around line 17500 (`:17500g` inside `less`):

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  512 ene 20 17:33 xzyzy
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  512 ene 20 17:33 xzyzz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  512 ene 20 17:33 xzzaaaa
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  512 ene 20 17:33 xzzaaab
```

So what's considered "most significant position" after the first increment.
Would the third increment be

```
zz zy zz
zz aa aa aa
```

and the fourth

```
zz zz zy zz 
zz aa aa aa aa
```

????

I'm not sure if I'm making any sense here or if I'm explaining my question correctly.

---

Increments

```
1st
zy
za aa

2nd
zy zz
zz aa aa

3rd?
zz zy zz 
zz aa aa aa
3rd??
[zz] zy zz 
[zz] zz aa aa

4th?
zz zz zy zz 
zz aa aa aa aa
4th?
[zz zz] zy zz 
[zz zz] zz aa aa
```

In the second 3rd?? and 4th?? options I take the suffixes between [] as if they're "locked" and treat the reminder as if it were the 2nd suffix increment.

Comment: Observation: there are 676 names from `aa` to `zz`, then there are 676 names from `zzaa` to `zzzz`, then 676 from `zzzzaa` to `zzzzzz`, and so on. The length would grow by 2 each 676 steps. It's linear growth, you would reach lengthy names fast. OTOH there are 650 names from `aa` to `yz`, then 16900 names from `zaaa` to `zyzz`, then 439400 names from `zzaaaa` to `zzyzzz`, then 11424400… Each time you need 26 times more steps then previously to reach the point where the length grows. It's logarithmic growth, it slows down quickly. Not an answer because I can only guess this is the reason.

Comment: The code I used to test without bothering any filesystem (GNU `split` required): `</dev/zero split -b 1 --filter='echo "$FILE"' | awk -F '' '{if (NF>lastn) print last"\n"NR-1"\n"$0"\n"; last=$0; lastn=NF}'`